# What does "In the grand scheme" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I've searched about `In the grand scheme` in Google but couldn't find a good answer. This context is part of an [article](http://www.phonearena.com/news/To-wearable-or-not-to-wearable_id64018) which is about wearable smart watches. And I don't know how translate `In the grand scheme` part in following context:

> There is no shortage of wearable gear out there, and really what I’m
>   writing about here is the latest crop of smartwatches, most of which
>   run on Android Wear. **In the grand scheme**, I know it is but a portion
>   of what many of us may use, be it Jawbone’s UP, or Fitbit, or
>   Samsung’s Tizen powered Galaxy Gear, and for me, it really comes down
>   to a single issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a contraction of a stock phrase, "In the grand scheme of things." This is a saying that probably derives from various religious sayings about "God's Plan," but is quite secular by now. It means, essentially, "Overall" or that there is a larger element of something. The author is acknowledging that they're focusing on *only* "the latest crop of Android smartwatches," and not *every* type of smartwatch or wearable device.